# How l can draw Hasse diagram

Tags: divisibility, relations

How can l draw a Hasse diagram of the divisibility relation, when $$B=\{2,4,5,6,7,10,18,20,24,25\}$$

Would any help, thank you.

Comment: Just connect $a$ and $b$ if $a\mid b$. Do you know which numbers divide which ones?

Comment: Start with all the primes at the bottom and build the diagram up connecting those with common divisors like $2$ and $5$ join $10$ and so on.

Comment: Yes but I cant draw it  because it is partial order relation

Comment: Can I draw it by parts beacuse 5 not divisible 2

Comment: Thank you very match Moo

Comment: @Moo I downvoted because your answer was simply wrong (and FredH already answered). Your diagram contained loops and arrows for divisibility relations that can be deduced by transitivity. Such kind of arrows never appear in the Hasse diagram in general.

Answer (score 1):

$2,5$ and $7$ are not divisible by any other numbers in the set, so they are on the lowest level.  $4,6$ and $10$ have other numbers ($18,20$ and $24$) that are multiples of them, so they are intermediate, while $18,20$ and $24$ are highest.  That leaves $25$, which is above $5$, but not below anything else; it's easiest to draw it on the middle level.  After rearranging things on each level to avoid crossing lines, it comes out like this:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
18&&24&&20\\
\huge|&\huge\diagup&\huge|&\huge\diagup&\huge|\\
6&&4&&10&&25\\
&\huge\diagdown&\huge|&\huge\diagup&\huge|&\huge\diagup\\
7&&2&&5
\end{array}
$$